# c# Dependency not getting instantiate

Tags: c#, instantiation

I have an abstract class with a dependency, I would to add a check to see if Loghelper is null and if it is create the object. The error that i am getting is the Loghelper can't be found?

> How do I instantiate dependency?

[image]

[image]

```
    public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
        {
            [Dependency]
            public ILogHelper LogHelper { get; set; }
private ILogHelper _logHelper;
        public ControllerBase(ILogHelper logHelper)
        {
            this._logHelper = logHelper;
        }
    public void ShowAlertMessage(string message, Messages type, bool session = false)
            {
                this.LogHelper = LogHelper;
                //if (null == LogHelper)
                //{
                //    LogHelper = new LogHelper();
                //}
                LogHelper.LogMessage("ShowAlertMessage: [" + type + "] " + message);

                if (!session)
                {
                    if (TempData[type.ToString()] != null)
                    {
                        TempData[type.ToString()] = message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData.Add(type.ToString(), message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Session[type.ToString()] != null)
                    {
                        Session[type.ToString()] = message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session.Add(type.ToString(), message);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `The error that i am getting is the Loghelper can't be found?` What exact error are you getting? Is it a compile time error? A runtime one?

Comment: same error its an compile error not sure what I am missing

Comment: @Marc 's answer below should work - but there is an alternate you can try. With your above code, remove `if (null == LogHelper)
            {
                LogHelper = new LogHelper();
            }` If you remove those lines, does it compile and run successfully?

Comment: Also please show us where you are registering your `ILogHelper` with your IoC container (I presume Unity?).

Answer (score 3):

You should have a constructor in which you pass in the dependency reference then set the property equal to that passed in parameter

```
    ...
    private ILogHelper _logHelper;

    public ControllerBase(ILogHelper logHelper)
    {
        this._logHelper = logHelper;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I have just the public ILogHelper LogHelper { get; set; }

Comment: @Jefferson then ignore the first line of Marc's answer (remove it) and change the assignment to `this.LogHelper = logHelper;`

Comment: LogHelper is still set to null error message is {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} Do I need new?

Comment: @Jefferson Please update your question (leave the old code here, add some extra code) to show the code you **tried** to implement Marc's answer.

Comment: You didn't implement Marc's answer properly. You didn't add the `public ControllerBase` constructor, for example.

Comment: @mjwills when I add the public controllerbase the solution will not build